# using brackets in printf not working correctly

Tags: c, linux

I am using GCC 6.4 and my printf statement is as follows:

```
printf("Initial Colour: RGB(%s,%s,%s)\n",userdata[k],userdata[k+1],userdata[k+2]);
```

It prints `)nitial Colour: RGB(1,0.0`  which is wrong. Note where the second bracket is printed.
It should be `Initial Colour: RGB(1,0.0)` as expected.

If I use GCC 4.5 with the same printf, it prints as expected.

What should my printf look like?

Comment: The `printf` is fine. Your data contains carriage return characters.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: RGB(%s,%s,%s) ->  output should be comma separated. RGB(1,0,0). Or tell how data is fed to the stout printf in your code?

Comment: What's the type of `userdata`?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a data file that was created on a Windows system.  Lines are terminated by `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed).  You are either processing this file on that same Windows system, but you are opening the file in binary (`"rb"`) mode.  Or, you are transferring the file to a Unix or Linux (or Mac) system and processing it there, but you are transferring it in a "binary" mode, that preserves the CRLF, without converting it to the Unix single-newline (`'\n'`) convention.

Then, you are reading lines of text, perhaps with `fgets`.  You are discarding the newline (`'\n'`), but you are not discarding the carriage return (`'\r'`).  So, each line ends with `\r`.

Then, you are splitting up the line into fields `userdata[0]`, `userdata[1]`, `userdata[2]`, ... .  I'm not sure if you're splitting it up at commas or at whitespace, but in any case, the `\r` is remaining attached to the last field.

Finally, when you print out that last field `userdata[k+2]`, that carriage return at the end of it is causing the cursor to return to the beginning of the line before the final `)` is printed.

You can fix this in several ways:

1. Don't create the file with `\r\n` in the first place.
2. If processing the file on a Windows system, open it in text (`"r"` or maybe `"rt"`) mode, not binary.
3. If transferring files from a Windows to a non-Windows system, use a "text" transfer mode that converts line endings.
4. When reading lines from the file, strip off trailing `\r` as well as `\n` characters.
5. If splitting fields on whitespace, include `'\r'` in the set of whitespace characters to split on.  For example, if you are calling `strtok`, with separators `" "` or `" \t"`, change to `" \r"` or `" \t\r"`.

Now that you've posted code, I can be more specific.

To achieve #4, add the line

```
if (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] == '\r') buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1]  = '\0';
```

after the line where you strip off the `\n`.

To achieve #5, change your two `strtok` calls to

```
data = strtok(buffer, " \r");
```

and

```
data = strtok(NULL, " \r");
```

As a matter of fact, you could also change those two lines to

```
data = strtok(buffer, " \r\n");
```

and

```
data = strtok(NULL, " \r\n");
```

and then you wouldn't need the newline-stripping step at all.

One more thing: your usage of `feof` is wrong.  See [Why is `while(!feof (fp))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).